# How to perform a Google search and take the text result?

Tags: python, dictionary, urllib, python-3.3, words

Wondering how to use Python 3 to use Google to create a dictionary of some words (so say I enter a word, I want Python to take the definition that Google is able to give, then store or display it)

I haven't done much coding, but I know how to manage the words after. I'm just a bit confused using urllib and stuff. I have only been able to find help for this on other versions of Python, which I have not been able to replicate on Python 3.3.

EDIT: Yes, I want to use Google because I like the way it defines words and phrases, and I plan to use the define protocol you mentioned, icedtrees.

Comment: Do the libraries out there work on python3? [pygoogle](https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/) or [google](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google/1.05) ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** it appears that Google Search grabs its definitions using AJAX calls or something. The below solution will not work.

---

If you are having trouble using urllib2, I suggest the nice [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package, which is a lot easier to use.

If you are absolutely committed to getting the Google definition and no other definition, I would suggest doing a HTTP request to a page using the Google Search "define" protocol.

For example:

```
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define:test
```

You would then save the HTML result, and then parse it for the definitions that you require. Some examples of Python HTML parsers are the [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) module, and also [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). However, this parsing operation seems pretty simple, so a basic regex should be more than enough. All definitions are stored as follows:

```
<div style="display:inline" data-dobid="dfn"> # the order of the style and the data-dobid can change
    <span>definition goes here</span>
</div>
```

An example of a regex to grab the definitions of "test" from the HTML page:

```
import re
definitions = re.findall(r'data-dobid="dfn".*?>.*?\<span>(.*?)</span>.*?</div>', html, re.DOTALL)

>>> len(definitions)
18
>>> definitions[0]
'a\n procedure intended to establish the quality, performance, or \nreliability of something, especially before it is taken into widespread \nuse.'
# Looks like you might need to remove the newlines
>>> definitions[5]
'the result of a medical examination or analytical procedure.'
```

As a sidenote, there also exists a [Google Dictionary API](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html), which can give you definition results in JSON format in response to a request.